# Why does this happen? (about the exchange of rows of matrix)

Tags: python

It is given that

```py
A = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [6, 5, 4],
       [3, 2, 1]])
```

and I want to exchange the second row and the third row. It doesn't matter how I should write the code, but I found something so strange.

Case 1:

```py
B = A
A[1,:] = B[2,:]
A[2,:] = B[1,:]
```

Case 2:

```py
B = []
B.append(A[1,:])
B.append(A[2,:])
A[2,:] = B[0]
A[1,:] = B[1]
```

Neither the case cannot realize what I want, since `B` is always changed even if just changing `A`. Why does it happen? In another different case but with a similar spirit, that is, given `a=2` and `b=1`, if we run

```
c = b
b = a
a = c
```

then the exchange will work well! Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are called by reference, atomic variables are called by value. Meaning, in the last example, `c` gets the *value* of `b`, but in the first case `A` and `B` are actually pointing to the same array, so your second line overwrites `A`. So, if you did `B=np.copy(A)`, all would be well.

Comment: So does the second case prove that lists are also called by reference? `B` is a list, but also changes when `A` changes.

Comment: @Thinkpad Yes, correct. This is why lists have a copy method as well.